# ¿ Cómo comparar dos arreglos de objetos y obtener objetos que no coincidan en un campo? Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy comparando dos arreglos, los cuales son los siguientes,
`configuraionesPersonalizadas`:

```
configuraionesPersonalizadas = [
    {
      id: 4163,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'id_docente',
      orden: 1,
      visible_cv_personalizado: true,
      mapeo: 'id_docente',
      id_user: 127,
    },
    {
      id: 4164,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'id',
      orden: 1,
      visible_cv_personalizado: true,
      mapeo: 'id',
      id_user: 127,
    },
    {
      id: 4165,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'fecha_emision',
      orden: 1,
      visible_cv_personalizado: true,
      mapeo: 'fecha_emision',
      id_user: 127,
    },
  ];
```

Y `configuraciones`:

```
  configuraciones = [
    {
      id: 179,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'id',
      mapeo: 'Id Grado Académico',
      usuario: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 180,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'id_docente',
      mapeo: 'id Docente',
      usuario: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 181,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'fecha_emision',
      mapeo: 'Fecha Emisión',
      usuario: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 182,
      bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
      atributo: 'lugar_emision',
      mapeo: 'Lugar Emisión',
      usuario: 1,
    },
  ];
```

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
 funcion() {
    this.configuraciones.forEach((atributo) => {
      let atribtutoOriginal = this.configuraionesPersonalizadas.find(
        (b) => b.atributo === atributo.atributo && b.bloque === atributo.bloque
      );

      if (
        atribtutoOriginal.bloque == atributo.bloque &&
        atribtutoOriginal.mapeo == atributo.mapeo
      )
        return;
      // console.log('sevaeditar', atributo, atribtutoOriginal);
      const objetoEditar = {
        id: atribtutoOriginal.id,
        bloque: atribtutoOriginal.bloque,
        atributo: atribtutoOriginal.atributo,
        orden: atribtutoOriginal.orden,
        visible_cv_personalizado: atribtutoOriginal.visible_cv_personalizado,
        mapeo: atributo.mapeo,
        id_user: Number(atribtutoOriginal.id_user),
      };

      console.log('objetoEditarconfiguraionesPersonalizadas', objetoEditar);
    });
  }
```

Está función me obtiene cuando el campo `mapeo` del arreglo `configuraionesPersonalizadas` no coincide con el campo `mapeo` del arreglo `configuraciones` en caso de que no coincida creo un objeto `objetoEditar` con el valor de `mapeo` de `cofiguraciones` para así poderlo editar.

Me funciona bien, el problema que tengo es que solamente me funciona cuando la longitud de los arreglos `configuraionesPersonalizadas` y `configuraciones` son iguales. En caso de que `configuraionesPersonalizadas` tenga menor longitud que `configurciones` me arroja el siguiente error.

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mapeo')
```

¿Cómo puedo optimizar o hacer para que me funcione sin necesidad de que la longitud de los arreglos sean iguales? Gracias de antemano.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l7gesl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenemos entonces

- un arreglo `configuraciones`, que contiene N settings oficiales de la aplicación. Cada setting tiene (simplificando mucho) el atributo a configurar, su valor por defecto (mapeo) y una jerarquía de agrupación (bloque)
- un arreglo de `configuracionesPersonalizadas` que permite modificar un subconjunto de lo anterior.

Para cada setting por defecto buscas un elemento en los settings personalizados que coincida tanto en grupo como en atributo

```
 let atribtutoOriginal = this.configuracionesPersonalizadas.find(
    (b) => b.atributo === atributo.atributo && b.bloque === atributo.bloque
  );
```

Si el valor (mapeo) coincide, no necesitas computar la mutación que diferencia ambas entradas, así que retornas

```
  if (
    atribtutoOriginal.bloque == atributo.bloque &&
    atribtutoOriginal.mapeo == atributo.mapeo
  )
    return;
```

Y si no coincide, ahí sí corresponde computar la mutación.

---

**Lo que  gatilla el error**  es el caso donde no hay `atribtutoOriginal` (`find` te entrega `undefined`) luego no es un objeto y no tiene internamente la lógica para pedir sus atributos `bloque` o `mapeo`.

De todos modos, cuando `atribtutoOriginal` es `undefined` tampoco necesitas computar la mutación ni  comparar nada.

```
if( !atribtutoOriginal 
   || (
        atribtutoOriginal.bloque == atributo.bloque &&
        atribtutoOriginal.mapeo == atributo.mapeo
      )
) return;
```

Sólo como observación, es redundante que vuelvas a comparar el *bloque*.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te comentaron, la validación en el condicional `if` que tiene que ver con el bloque, es innecesaria ya que la haces en el `find`.

Ahora bien, la solución que le daría sería mediante **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**, y por cada iteración, armamos el objeto que necesitas de acuerdo a la condición que requieres.

```js
const configuraionesPersonalizadas = [
    {
        id: 4163,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'id_docente',
        orden: 1,
        visible_cv_personalizado: true,
        mapeo: 'id_docente',
        id_user: 127
    },
    {
        id: 4164,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'id',
        orden: 1,
        visible_cv_personalizado: true,
        mapeo: 'id',
        id_user: 127
    },
    {
        id: 4165,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'fecha_emision',
        orden: 1,
        visible_cv_personalizado: true,
        mapeo: 'fecha_emision',
        id_user: 127
    }
];

const configuraciones = [
    {
        id: 179,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'id',
        mapeo: 'Id Grado Académico',
        usuario: 1
    },
    {
        id: 180,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'id_docente',
        mapeo: 'id Docente',
        usuario: 1
    },
    {
        id: 181,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'fecha_emision',
        mapeo: 'Fecha Emisión',
        usuario: 1
    },
    {
        id: 182,
        bloque: 'GradoAcademico',
        atributo: 'lugar_emision',
        mapeo: 'Lugar Emisión',
        usuario: 1
    }
];

(() => {
    const aux = configuraciones.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        const item = configuraionesPersonalizadas.find(x => x.atributo === curr.atributo && x.bloque === curr.bloque);

        if (item && item.mapeo !== curr.mapeo) {
            const { id, bloque, atributo, orden, visible_cv_personalizado, mapeo, id_user } = item;
            const objeto = {
                id,
                bloque,
                atributo,
                orden,
                visible_cv_personalizado,
                mapeo,
                id_user: +id_user
            };
            prev = [...prev, objeto];
        }

        return prev;
    }, []);

    console.log(aux);
})();
```

De hecho, no es muy diferente de lo que tienes. Estamos obteniendo mediante `find` el objeto concordante; luego validamos en el `if`, que haya encontrado alguna coincidencia y comparamos su propiedad *mapeo*. En caso de no cumplir la condición, armamos el objeto y lo *pusheamos* al arreglo *prev*.

Nos comentas que tal te fue y si tienes alguna duda :)